# Archestra list all engines on a platform

Tags: enumerate

I need to write a script able to print a list of all the engines existing on an Archestra platform.
I've tried to create a script at the platform level, but haven't found anywhere information about how to obtain the engines list, the same way for instance IDE is doing it.
Anybody has idea of this?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the IDE uses SQL to populate the tree. There is a table with all the properties of the object, including where the object is running.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the exact same mechanism as the ArchestrA IDE, but there are several options:

1. Externally build and save the Galaxy hierarchy using `GRAccess`. This
   is the recommended technique.
2. Connect directly to the Galaxy database and build the hierarchy. This not an officially supported technique, but it is very fast.
3. Build the list of Engines through scripting, either using `MXAccess` or possibly from an ArchestrA script.

For #3 `MXAccess`/Scripting, it is possible to add relative tags to find the engines:

1. `MyPlatform._Engines[-1]` -> iterate through to get the engines
2. `${EngineName}.Objects[-1]` -> if needed, lists the objects in the engine
3. `MyPlatform.Tagname` -> name of Platform
4. `MyPlatform.Host` -> host name of Platform

If you try the ArchestrA scripting route, you will need to use the `Indirect` type and `BindTo`, but realize the asynchronous nature of the responses so it will require delays and polling to see if the data is available. Usually communication in the same engine is fairly quick though.